# Deserializing xml-files with different namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I want to import xml-files with different namespaces, but a similar structure. I haven`t found a solution that suits my needs so I am asking now.

How can I establish to ignore the namespaces. Or how could I remove the tag before deserializing?

The error-message I am getting:

```
<Root xmlns='namespace...'> was not expected.
```

The way I deserialize the xml-files:

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path))
{
    xmlObject = (XmlClass)new 
    XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlClass)).Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: Error message indicates the Xml is bad.

Comment: Yes, because in my XmlClasses i declared no namespace, but the imported xml has one

Comment: You can't delete a namespace if the tags use the namespace.  The xml becomes invalid.  The right way of doing this is to make the xml parsing to dynamically use the namespaces in the file or ignore the namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a very simple namespace stripper by subclassing `XmlTextReader`. This class seems to be enough for `XmlDeserializer`:

```
public class XmlReaderNoNamespaces : XmlTextReader
{
    public XmlReaderNoNamespaces(Stream stream) : base(stream)
    {
    }

    public override string Name => LocalName;

    public override string NamespaceURI => string.Empty;

    public override string Prefix => string.Empty;
}
```

Use it like:

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path))
using (var reader = new XmlReaderNoNamespaces(stream))
{
    xmlObject  =(FooContainer)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```